# Fixed within one class intercepts, fixed within another class regression coefficients, and errors; as columns in a tibble

Tags: r, purrr, tidymodels

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)

Tibble = tibble(
  Class1 = rep(c("TITUS","CAIUS"),27),
  Class2 = rep(c("A","A","A",
             "B","B","B",
             "C","C","C"),6
             ),
  Outcome = rnorm(54,5,2),
  Predictor = Outcome + rnorm(54,0,2.5),
  alpha = NA,
  beta = NA)

lmer(data = Tibble,
     Outcome ~ (0 + (Class1) + (0 + Predictor|(Class2)))) %>%
  tidy(effects = c("fixed","ran_coefs")) -> model

for(i in 1:54) {
  
  Tibble$alpha[i] <- model %>%
    filter(effect == "fixed",
           term == str_c("Class1",Tibble$Class1[i])) %>%
    pull(estimate)
  
  Tibble$beta[i] <- model %>%
    filter(effect == "ran_coefs",
           level == Tibble$Class2[i],
           term == "Predictor") %>%
    pull(estimate)
}

Tibble %>% mutate(
  Predicted = (alpha + Predictor*beta),
  epsilon = Outcome - Predicted) -> Tibble

Tibble %>% summarise(cor(Predicted,Outcome, method = "kendall"),
                     )
```

Key concepts: there is a `alpha` for each class1- There is a `beta` for each `class2`.
Epsilon is the residual.

I want to make the code above faster without recurring to a `for` cycle.
Also, I am very worried about the regression model, because I plan to do it in a `tibble` with more than 1 million observation, 600k `class1`, 40k `class2`.

Notice that that model `formula` and the regression package is only one possible combination and you can give suggestions. I am most interested in alpha's estimation, not in minimizing epsilons.

Comment: I think your description here of your goal (`alpha`, `beta`) is somewhat unclear (I can't quite understand what you are wanting to do). Can you edit the question to make it more clear, perhaps show an example of what you want to do for a single row or set of values?

Comment: I think it's easier to understand the regression model through the last paragraph of the edit. If one decompose the database in groups of Class1, then the problem is just a problem of fixed coefficients within groups. However, I want to use information on the whole dataset to determine alphas and betas.

Comment: If unclear, I could try to build a for cycle in another edit. The key is that for row 1:
 TITUS and A; then I look for fixed estimates in the subset of Tibble where Class1==TITUS and/or Class2==A.

Comment: I don't believe you can train models like this with `lm()`. If you can show one example model with this data, that would be helpful. Check out [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) to help you build reproducible examples.

Comment: with `lm()`, the model could account for Class1 as a nominal intercept and wrong regression statistics; and I think it's true there is now way to account for fixed effects in `lm()`. But there are different packages for fixed effects, all with different syntaxes; hence the pseudocode.
In the next hours/days I will set a for cycle, instead of pseudocode.